# Explanation of reportAttributeAccessIssue of pylance

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

I have following class

```py
class ProcessRunner:

    def __init__(self, network: nn.Module) -> None:
        self.network: nn.Module = network

    def run(self, processes: List[Process]):
        for process in processes:
            process.network = self.network
            self.network = process.update()
```

Which shows in function `run` for `self.network` and `process.update()` following Errors:

```
Cannot assign member "network" for type "Process"
  Type "Module | None" cannot be assigned to type "Module"
    "None" is incompatible with "Module"PylancereportAttributeAccessIssue
```

and

```
Cannot assign member "network" for type "ProcessRunner*"
  "None" is incompatible with "Module"PylancereportAttributeAccessIssue
```

I think I understand that those issues a are partial coming from my Protocol Class `Process`, which looks like this:

```py
@runtime_checkable
class Process(Protocol):

    network: nn.Module

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        ...
```

But I do not understand completely what causes the issue here:

1. The second issue might appear because, the `update` method doesn't return the network here. Okay solution could be that the network is only part of the `ProcessRunner` class. But how can a method access it in this case?
2. I have no clue what the first issues triggers. The object in the Protocol class as well in the `ProcessRunner` class are both of type `nn.Module`. Why is it not satisfied then? or is this an issue which appears by the second issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are assigning the result of `process.update()` to `self.network`, which is inferred to be `None`.

`self.network` has the type of, as you would expect, `Module`. `None` clearly isn't of the same type, hence the first error:

```
Cannot assign member "network" for type "ProcessRunner*"
  "None" is incompatible with "Module"
```

Now that you have assigned `None` to `self.network`, Pyright thinks that it is of type `Module | None`. However, `Process.network` is of type `Module`, so a second error is reported:

```
Cannot assign member "network" for type "Process"
  Type "Module | None" cannot be assigned to type "Module"
    "None" is incompatible with "Module"
```

One solution is to explicitly specify the types:

<sub>([playground link](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.12&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoCCKcANFCAK4oxYCmA%2BgMYAWtjA1gIYBGANrWQAK4GGEZheAWABQMmY16cAzkqgBZMABMK-AFwyohqAmVK5s6QAFK1Ok1Yce-eYpVRhY2ioAUH0eN4ASn0LIygUWhgAd1x2XXUtHVpzMM1aYCgKBE1OGFpvJVpeYDIAKlL2KM4QNCV4ojhAqABaAD4E7T0DMKMAOn7zF1N3cEYvJQAlKgiQEO7DNIz6elQkGGWCopLwyJiQOI6kpraoADkwCJCeo0Li3ojo2PiNTtooAF4dx-2Uo0XyKibYpkBCjcZeeK8JBKGAAbQ8YxUAF1gvMesBcMYwW5UFjPCoIWjroZQfilPddrEPlBbsAKd92ETibT6Xt2NTSYjyVkcnlvIEZEA))</sub>

```py
@runtime_checkable
class Process(Protocol):
    network: Module

    def update(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Module:
        ...
```

If `.update()` is not intended to return anything, then don't assign that to `self.network`:

<sub>([playground link](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.12&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoCCKcANFCAK4oxYCmA%2BgMYAWtjA1gIYBGANrWQAK4GGEZheAWABQMmY16cAzkqgBZMABMK-AFwyohqAmVK5s6QAFK1Ok1Yce-eYpVRhY2ioAUH0eN4ASn0LIygUWhgAd1x2XXUtHVpzMM1aYCgKBE1OGFpvJVpeYDIAKlL2KM4QNCV4ojhAqABaAD4oADkwCJCwsIA6QfMXU3dwRi8lACUqCJAQgyM0jPp6VCQYVYKikvDImJA4hO1%2BJrbO7tpevsNC4v6I6Nj4jRPaKABePafDlKX08hUbbFMgIcaTLzxXhIJQwADaHgmKgAusFFjdgLhjOC3KhsZ4VJD0TcjGCCUoHvtYp8oHdgJSfuxiST8UiKVkcnlvIFmSS6QyDuwaWS2QLYjIgA))</sub>

```py
    def run(self, processes: list[Process]):
        for process in processes:
            process.network = self.network
            process.update()
            self.network = process.network
```

You could also define a more ergonomic `Process` interface:

<sub>([playground link](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.12&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoCCKcANFCAK4oxYCmA%2BgMYAWtjA1gIYBGANrWQAK4GGEZheAWABQMmY16cAzkqgBZMABMK-AFwyohqAmVK5s6QAFK1Ok1Yce-eYpVRhY2ioAUH0eN4ASn0LIyhNWmAoCgRNThhabyVaXmAyFFoYAHdcdl11LR0BKAAqEvYszhA0JXyiOECoAFoAPigAOTAMkLCwgDoB8xdTd3BGLyUAJSoMkBCDIwio%2BnpUJBgVpJS0qAzs3PyNbX5G1o6u2h7ew2TUvr2ckDyC49ooAF5dzMf2czCl8hULapMgIMYTLz5XhIJQwADaHnGKgAusEFtdgLhjOC3KhsZ4VJD0dcjGCCUo%2BjE4glgcB7t9coEZEA))</sub>

```py
@runtime_checkable
class Process(Protocol):

    def update(self, network: Module, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        ...
```

```py
class ProcessRunner:

    def run(self, processes: list[Process]):
        for process in processes:
            process.update(self.network)
```